# ogr2ogr not running on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I'm trying to convert an [osm.pbf file to a spatialite db](https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/) but I can't get ogr2ogr to run.

I have qgis 2.14.2 and ubuntu 15.10.  I've reinstalled gdal-bin and I'm getting the following message from the terminal:

> ogr2ogr: error while loading shared libraries: libcharset.so.1: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've searched numerous places and I keep ending up back at instructions to install gdal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you install qgis and gdal? From source or some repository? It looks like you are missing `libcharset` which probably comes from `iconv`. Possibly a missing dependency in the repository package spec or a failed install from source...

Comment: I installed from qgis.org.  I'll see if I can install the package you referenced.

Comment: So I went back and checked;  I installed gdal with `sudo apt-get install gdal-bin`, although I can't find the repository.  QGIS i installed from the ubuntugis repository.  I installed `iconv` earlier this morning but it still didn't run.

Comment: so I ran it on my desktop which has (I thought) the identical configuration to my laptop - ogr2ogr runs fine.  Re-installed GDAL and QGIS on the maptop, not sure why it's still not working.